# DHCP Server: Missing Addresses and how to free them

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012-r2, dhcp, domain-controller

Our DHCP Server, running on a Windows Server 2012 R2 Data Center, shows that we have 241 addresses total with 220 (91%) in use, 21 available. If I go to the Address Leases node and count all IP addresses manually, I get 78 IP addresses.

**Where are the remaining addresses and how do I free them?**

I already set the DHCP server scope and lowered the lease time to 1-hour on both boxes, rebooted them, and waited a day, and I still see 220 in use. We only have about the 78 devices, so that number is right, just I am at a loss of where the remaining IP addresses are, how to see them, and how to free them?

It would seem some sort of configuration, but the DHCP does not have that many options. Is there a cache or something?

[image: DHCP Server Screenshot]

I did see a [page](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/533408-dhcp-server-leases-100-used-showing-ip-in-cient-ip-and-name-fields) stating to delete all the addresses during off hours, however I can delete the 78 shown in "Address Leases" for the sub-net. What I cannot do is delete the roughly 120 other IP addresses. Why do I not see them? Yes, this article states deleting the scope and recreating it and possibly deleting the server roll and recreating that, but that is harsh. At first, I would like to see all the 220 IP addresses that are supposedly "in use".

**UPDATE: PER REQUEST**

Address Scope:

[image: DHCP Address Scope]

Reservation List

[image: DHCP Reservation List]

Address Leases Ordered by IP

[image: DHCP Leases Ordered by IP]

Address Pool Showing No Exclusion Ranges

[image: DHCP Pool Showing No Exclusion Ranges]

So for instance, where are .46, .47, .48, or any of the other unused addresses?

Comment: Please provide the following:  The overall pool, the exclusion range(s), any reservations within the scope.  A screenshot or shots of the outstanding leases (ordered by IP address) could be helpful too.

Comment: FYI: Reservations will show up under the Address Leases node along with dynamic leases.

Comment: @RobPearson Post updated with additional information showing all requested information. There are no exclusion ranges. Reservations and everything else showing. So where are .46, .47, .48, and all the others? How do I free them up?

Comment: @joeqwerty I updated the question showing your requested information.

Comment: OK, a quick note: Your images are from two different Scopes. Can you post images from only the affected Scope?

Comment: @joeqwerty Apologies. I updated the first screenshot. The dialog showing the statistics was correct, just a bit clearer now. Everything should align nicely now for the question, which is on the 192.168.20.* subnet.